# How to Rotate a Circle Around Its Own Midpoint

Tags: opengl, rotation

I have rendered a circle using OBJ file. Now I want to rotate it around its own axis, like YouTube buffering icon.  How can I do that? I'm working in OpenGL.

I can change its x, y, and z rotation using a transformation matrix.

Comment: What did you try that did not work?

Comment: How are you drawing the circle? We can't tell you what axis to rotate around if we don't know what plane it's drawn in.